# Javascript regex causing browser hanging

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, pattern-matching

I'm trying to parse a stacktrace with regex, but it seems that it has either some major performance issues, or something more horribly wrong. When I have it run in code, the browser seems to hang forever, tho when I run it in the console, it takes maybe 10 or 15 seconds to return. I'm testing in chrome.

Here's an example:

```
"Object.printStackTrace.implementation.createException (file:///F:/billysFile/code/javascript/nodejs/deadunit/browserPackage/deadunit.browser.gen.umd.js:942:19)"
  .match(/^(((new )?[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*(.[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*)*)\(\)@((?:http|https|file):\/\/[^\s)]+|javascript:.*)(:(\d*):(\d*))|((new )?[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*(.[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*)*) \(((?:http|https|file):\/\/[^\s)]+|javascript:.*)(:(\d*):(\d*))\)|((new )?[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*(.[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*)*) (\(native\)))$/)
```

and here's the original regex before composition:

```
"Object.printStackTrace.implementation.createException (file:///F:/billysFile/code/javascript/nodejs/deadunit/browserPackage/deadunit.browser.gen.umd.js:942:19)".match(CHROME_STACK_LINE)

var IDENTIFIER_PATTERN_ = '[a-zA-Z_$][\\w$]*';
var URL_PATTERN_ = '((?:http|https|file)://[^\\s)]+|javascript:.*)';

var CHROME_FILE_AND_LINE = URL_PATTERN_+'(:(\\d*):(\\d*))'
var CHROME_COMPOUND_IDENTIFIER = "((new )?"+IDENTIFIER_PATTERN_+'(\\.'+IDENTIFIER_PATTERN_+')*)'

var CHROME_ANONYMOUS_FUNCTION = CHROME_COMPOUND_IDENTIFIER+'\\(\\)'+'@'+CHROME_FILE_AND_LINE
var CHROME_NORMAL_FUNCTION = CHROME_COMPOUND_IDENTIFIER+' \\('+CHROME_FILE_AND_LINE+'\\)'
var CHROME_NATIVE_FUNCTION = CHROME_COMPOUND_IDENTIFIER+' (\\(native\\))'

var CHROME_FUNCTION_CALL = '('+CHROME_ANONYMOUS_FUNCTION+"|"+CHROME_NORMAL_FUNCTION+"|"+CHROME_NATIVE_FUNCTION+')'
var CHROME_STACK_LINE = new RegExp('^'+CHROME_FUNCTION_CALL+'$')
```

Am I doing something horribly wrong here? It doesn't look to me like [catastrophic backtracing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html)..

Comment: Congratulations! You do indeed have a pathological regular expression of some sort. `(.[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*)*` could be the culprit.

Comment: Maybe I should just use PEG..

Comment: Maybe you should split on `" "`. Depending on what you’re trying to extract.

Comment: I think changing . to \. might actually have solved it. I really was trying to match a dot, not anything - oops. BB in a second with results!

Comment: You need to re-evaluate what comes after 'new' in that regex. This `( . [a-zA-Z_$] [\w$]* )*` dot in there is a major problem.

Comment: It did in fact solve it! Thanks so much for your help! Good eye. Write it up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `( . [a-zA-Z_$] [\w$]* )*` dot in there is a major problem.
Change it to `\.` maybe?

This is your expanded regex.
Get a tool like [RegexFormat4](http://www.regexformat.com) to look at your
large regex's.

```
 ^
 (
      (
           ( new\  )?
           [a-zA-Z_$] [\w$]* 
           ( . [a-zA-Z_$] [\w$]* )*
      )
      \(\)@
      (
           (?: http | https | file )
           :// [^\s)]+ 
        |  javascript: .* 
      )
      (
           :
           ( \d* )
           :
           ( \d* )
      )
   |  (
           ( new\  )?
           [a-zA-Z_$] [\w$]* 
           ( . [a-zA-Z_$] [\w$]* )*
      )
      \ \(
      (
           (?: http | https | file )
           :// [^\s)]+ 
        |  javascript: .* 
      )
      (
           :
           ( \d* )
           :
           ( \d* )
      )
      \)
   |  (
           ( new\  )?
           [a-zA-Z_$] [\w$]* 
           ( . [a-zA-Z_$] [\w$]* )*
      )
      \ 
      ( \(native\) )
 )
 $
```